# Complete online reference for the C standard library?

Tags: c, reference

Have any of you got a link to an online reference that completely decribes the C(99) standard library?

When i say describes, i mean something i can keep open and refer to when im coding.

I'm looking for something along the lines of [DevGuru ECMA script Reference](http://www.devguru.com/Technologies/ecmascript/quickref/javascript_index.html) but for the C standard library.

Comment: I've found [this reference](http://www.utas.edu.au/infosys/info/documentation/C/CStdLib.html) useful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found this one, which is C99. Look under the '*C Headers*' heading.

http://www.dinkumware.com/manuals/

Comment: This accepted answer's link is a 404 not found.

Answer (score 12):

The standard you're looking for [ISO/IEC 9899](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=29237) available from ISO for the low low price of 352 Swiss Francs.  I like to have the standard around, it pays to have the authoritative version especially when doing cross-compiler work.  Whatever you do, don't Google for C99.pdf as that might find you bootlegged copies.

For reference I like to refer to [Open Group's POSIX standard](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/idx/headers.html) which also lets you know what's a POSIX extension and what's ISO C99.

Comment: That's around USD$345 (says Google); not exactly what I would consider a "low, low price," even for an ISO/IEC publication.

Comment: Oh, no! I ignored your advice and accidentally downloaded a bootleg copy!

Comment: @James  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5j7ftfRiWlg

@uncleo  ZOUNDS!!

Comment: oh man, if I only new about that ISO/IEC 9899 by the time I was at College my life would've been so much easier! :P

Answer (score 2):

Here is a C library reference guide (for C90). I like this one because of it's  "Tastes great / less filling" website design.

[ACM C Library Guide](http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/)

Answer (score 2):

I use the PDF from [the official home of ISO/ IEC JTC1/SC22/WG14 - C](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/).

Click [9899: Programming Language C](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/projects#9899) and you can download the "most current draft of the revised C99 standard" for free.

Answer (score 2):

yep this one her http://code-reference.com/c
there you can find a lots of examples and descriptions of functions for C Programming

Answer (score 1):

There are three sources of information here that I can point you in the direction of:

- n843.pdf ([here](http://www.dkuug.dk/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n843.pdf) - that is the C99 standard)
- C FAQ ([here](http://c-faq.com/))
- C API (as defined by opengroup [here](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/))

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Answer (score 0):

[C++ Reference](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/) also contains information about the [standard C library](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/c/start) (C90).

Answer (score 0):

http://cplusplus.com/reference/ has a complete listing.

Comment: Watch out, that's C90 and will be missing features and functions.